Http 400 error due to MinRequestBodyDataRate with custom TextInputFormatter
Using ASP.NET Core 2.2, my REST API in production encounters sporadic bad request errors:

Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate

In production environment, the requests are usually a mix of fast and slow mobile connections.
I managed to reproduce those errors in test environment, using a moderate load (max 6 simultaneous requests) of slow connections by throttling Jmeter request to 2048 byte/s (which, by itself, shouldn't be low enough to trigger the 240B/s MinbodyDataRate Kestrel setting)
The exception is raised in a custom TextInputFormatter class, on the JArray.Load call:
public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
{
        var stream = context.HttpContext.Request.Body;

        using (var reader = context.ReaderFactory(stream, encoding))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            // Don't close the request stream because you many need it in other middleware or controllers.
            jsonReader.CloseInput = false;

            bool isSuccessful = true;
            List<BaseCommand> model = null;

            try
            {
                Assembly assembly = typeof(BaseCommand).Assembly;

                // here we're reading and parsing the json array directly from the stream
                var objCollection = JArray.Load(jsonReader);
                Log.Information("Json message:{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCollection));

                model = objCollection
                    .Select((obj) =>
                    {
                        // here some code mapping the incoming data to the internal type BaseCommand
                        // ...

                        return mappedCmd;
                    }).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "Error parsing BaseCommand");
                isSuccessful = false;
            }

            if (isSuccessful)
            {
                if (model == null && !context.TreatEmptyInputAsDefaultValue)
                    return InputFormatterResult.NoValueAsync();
                else
                    return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(model);
            }

            return InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
}

Once there are 5 or 6 active requests at the same time on the server (according to our HaProxy), we start getting around 12% errors.
Typical Json payload are between 1kB and 20kB in size.
If I do the same Jmeter test without throttling, the number of active requests on the server stays around 1, and we have no error.
After reading this thread, I suspected thread starvation, and so I asynchronized the method (using await JArray.LoadAsync() instead of JArray.Load()) and also increased the MinThread number of the threadpool (10 instead of 1): Contrary to my expectation, it had no effect at all!
I checked the CPU and memory diagnostics, and they're not saturated : never above 15% CPU and 10% memory.
The API is currently hosted in a linux docker container using a linux (alpine) image.
Am I missing a way my code is ruining the API's performance or should I just limit the number of incoming request to avoid this error?

Tons of performance improvements where made since asp.net-core 2. Maybe it's worth considering a new dotnet version.

@jeb Yes it is considered. But being a legacy project with one or maybe two year left to live, I'm weighing which are the lowest hanging fruits. I'm also genuinely curious at what could limit the API's performance if it's not CPU, memory or thread starvation...

I'm getting the same on .Net 8, Azure App service (Linux). I increased MinRequestBodyDataRate and it reduced errors by 50%. The client devices are GSM devices 2G/3G/4G.

@AHoughton Ok, then I guess your poor-connection-clients are getting more errors, maybe freeing some ressource for some fast-connection-client.
